# How to find where function is being used

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a function named `func1`. It's used somewhere in the database but I don't know where.

I wrote this query to help me find where it's being used:

```
select proname,prosrc
from pg_proc
where prosrc like '%func1%';
```

How can I modify this query to check if triggers use `func1` as well?

Comment: `LIKE` is case-sensitive. You probably want `ILIKE` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know it's a trigger function (i.e. `RETURNS TRIGGER`), this should do it:

```
SELECT tgname, tgrelid::regclass
FROM pg_trigger
WHERE tgfoid = 'func1'::regproc
```

If `func1` is overloaded, you would need to use e.g. `tgfoid = 'func1(text,text)'::regprocedure`.

But in general, it might also appear in `pg_aggregate`, or `pg_cast`, or in a view definition, or a check constraint, or a dozen other places, and you don't want to have to check them all.

You can get to the bottom of this via [`pg_depend`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/catalog-pg-depend.html), which tracks all object dependencies in the database. For example:

```
SELECT classid::regclass
FROM pg_depend
WHERE refobjid = 'func1'::regproc
```

If this returns e.g. [`pg_attrdef`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/catalog-pg-attrdef.html), then you know it's used in a column default. The other fields in `pg_depend` will tell you exactly which table/column it is. Note that a call from another function is not considered to be a dependency, so you still need to check `pg_proc.prosrc`.

But there's a simpler way to track down the majority of dependencies:

```
BEGIN;
DROP FUNCTION func1();
ROLLBACK;
```

If `func1` is being used, the `DROP` will (probably) fail, and the error will tell you exactly where.

Even easier, if you've got a shell handy: Just to run `pg_dump --schema-only` and see where `func1` turns up.

Comment: I thought more of something like search the word 'func1' in all Trigger text code. same as I did with functions... prosrc is the code of the function. so i'm searching in the code for func1

Comment: @John: Postgres doesn't store the text form of the trigger definition. It parses it, and puts each component in the appropriate field in `pg_trigger`. The name of the function is replaced with the internal identifier of the function, and stored in `pg_trigger.tgfoid`.

Answer (score -1):

```
select
    object_name(m.object_id) [object_name], m.definition
from
    sys.sql_modules m
where
    m.definition like N'%func1%'
```

Comment: Please add some information about your solution on why and how it solves the problem?

Comment: maybe not postgresql SQL ?