# Check if a view is used in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, view, postgresql-9.1

I am having a view in PostgreSQL and i want to check where all places the view is being referenced. I know the below query which will search  in all the procedures & functions  and will return if it is used.

```
select * from pg_proc where prosrc ilike '%someview%';
```

Is there any other way or any alternate solution?

Comment: Have a look at the `pg_depend` catalog table.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30896701/1104979); most of this can be applied to views as well. If you want to try the `pg_depend` approach mentioned there, the `WHERE` clause in your case would be `refobjid = 'someview'::regclass`.